# if(T is classname) is not working: T is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, generics, operator-keyword, keyword, typeof

I want to check if generic type T is a Student class or whatever.

in If statement, I do this:

```
if (T is Student)
{
    // Do sth.
}
```

and it doesn't compile and says :

> T is a type, which is not valid in the given context

I know the code below will work instead:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Student))
{
    // Do sth.
}
```

But I just liked to use `is` keyword because it is makes my code more readable.

What is the reason of that error and is there any way to use is or not?

Comment: but `is` works only for instance ... you cannot do `Type1 is Type2` you can only do `instance is Type`

Comment: apart from the synatcial problem you also have a semantic-problem: generics - as the name suggests - should work for *all* types. Performing any typechecks on the type-parameter pretty much contraditcs their idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the reason of that error?

The reason is that you are asking whether a certain `Type` is (or might be) something else than a of type `Type`. and the answer is clearly a NO.

> and is there any way to use is or not?

Yes there is, but for that you would need an instance of the object like `T myObject` then you can ask

```
if (myObject is Student)
{
    // Do sth.
}
```

Imagine a realworld scenario, where you have a human named Peter. Peter is the instance of the type human. In your example you are trying to ask: "if human is a student ...". which is rather difficult to understand or in compiler language:

> not valid in the given context

whereas asking "if Peter is a student.." sounds much more comprehensivly, even for a C# compiler ;)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, by the way the "if student is human" will make sence... But I got the point, thank you.